# Why doesn't docker run support using --rm and -d at the same time?

Tags: docker

Docker's documentation says that --rm and -d cannot be used together: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-d

Why? I seem to be misunderstanding what "detached" means; it seems entirely orthogonal to what --rm does. Why are they mutually exclusive?

By way of analogy, if I start a process in the background (e.g. start my-service), and the process exits, the process's resources are freed automatically (by init). It doesn't stick around, waiting for me to manually remove it. Why doesn't docker allow me to combine -d with --rm so that my container works in an analogous way?

I think that would address a very common use case. Seems that it would very nicely obviate the following work around: https://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2015/11/03/Docker-and-Upstart/

What am I missing???

Answer (score 3):

Because `--rm` is implemented as a client-side option: when you specify `--rm`, the docker *client* waits around for the container to exit, and then removes it.

When you specify `-d`, the docker client *exits*.  The container is running and is managed by the Docker server.  There is no longer any client running to implement the `--rm` functionality.

Comment: note that this may change in docker 1.12; there's an open pull-request to move the removal to the daemon; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20848

Answer (score 2):

As a way of answering, lets imagine i launch a container using `-d` and `--rm` and this is allowed. `docker run -d --rm --name=my_app my_container`

If my app works as expected it will run and when it come time to die, it dies and quietly removes itself, meaning I can rerun this command with little hassle. This seems ideal, and your question was one I faced myself while setting up some docker automation for my project.

What if, however, something goes wrong, the process running in the container encounters a fatal error and crashes, causing the container to die. The problem is that, to any outside observer, be they human or monitoring software, will not be able to tell the difference between these two scenarios, except maybe by how long the container was alive.

In cases where -d is not used, running a command in CLI or using upstart/initd/systemd/other, the container writes output, which will remain even if the container was given `--rm`, allowing an error or crash to be noticed and resolved.

In cases where `-d` is used, not binding container output to any output stream or file, `--rm` is not allowed to ensure that there is evidence left behind, in the form of a dead container, of an error/crash.

**To wrap up/TL;DR:** I believe this conscious choice was made by docker developers to prevent cases in which containers were completely unaccounted for with the trade-off being the need to add two more commands to your automation script.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.13, you now can use `--rm` with background jobs. The remove operation has been moved from the client to the server to enable this.

See the following pull request for more details: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20848

Here's an example of this new behavior:

```
$ docker run -d --rm --name sleep busybox sleep 10
be943302d668f6416b083b8b6fa74e254b8e4200d14f6d7743d48691db1a4b18

$ docker ps | grep sleep
be943302d668        busybox             "sleep 10"               4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                                 sleep

$ sleep 10; docker ps | grep sleep
```